# Animate scrollLeft jQuery code not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, horizontal-scrolling, mousewheel

I'm currently using this code to make my div scroll horizontally by mousewheel:

```
    $(".row-horizon").mousewheel(function(event) {
    if (event.deltaY > 0){
     $(".row-horizon").animate({scrollLeft : '-=300'}, 'slow');
    } else if (event.deltaY < 0) {
     $(".row-horizon").animate({scrollLeft :'+=300'}, 'slow');
    }
    });
```

[Here is a JSFiddle with same jQuery.](https://jsfiddle.net/jwv8g69m/)

That should work fine, except it bugs up my page.
When I scroll too fast on it, it just gets stuck, and I can't do anything until is unfreezes again.

Is there any other way to do this, or fix this code?
Thank you

Comment: By 'gets stuck' you mean that it animates till the end of the div?

Comment: @DanielStasiak No, it literally gets stuck, gets stuck and i cant scroll anywhere